# Profile OpenMP Code With Intel VTune XE

Tags: c++, openmp, profiler, icc

I have a really weird bug in my code where when running in the Intel XE profiler, it crashes out before the OpenMP section.

If I run the command:

```
./sphere_benchmark -i ../sphere_team6_dealmesh.prm -m 2 -h 1 -p 3
```

top shows 100% CPU usage in a small serial section, spinning up to 1200% when it drops into the OpenMP block.

However if I run the command:

```
amplxe-cl -collect concurrency -- ./sphere_benchmark -i ../sphere_team6_dealmesh.prm -m 2 -h 1 -p 3
```

I see the same 100% serial section, but then it stops, and claims there were no profiled regions, as it's looking to profile concurrency. If I change the metric to 'advanced-hotspots', it does profile the code, but only the lines prior to the OpenMP section! (Note - I am using absolute paths in reality, omitted here for brevity).

However if my application is crashing before the OpenMP section, which I assume it is, it must be a very clean crash as I get no error, no warning, nothing untoward going on even specifying -vv to `amplxe-cl`. And it runs fine when not being profiled.

The program I am using relies on the [dealii](https://dealii.org/) library, which has been built from source using icc 16.0.1, and has all of it's many dependencies built from source with the same.

My compile command looks a bit like:

```
mpiicpc -DDEBUG -DTBB_DO_ASSERT=1 -DTBB_IMPLEMENT_CPP0X=1 -DTBB_USE_DEBUG -qopenmp -I<incs> -fpic -ansi -w2 -wd68 -wd135 -wd175 -wd177 -wd191 -wd193 -wd279 -wd327 -wd383 -wd981 -wd1418 -wd1478 -wd1572 -wd2259 -wd21 -wd2536 -wd15531 -wd111 -wd128 -wd185 -wd280 -qopenmp-simd -std=c++11 -Wno-return-type -Wno-parentheses -O0 -g -gdwarf-2 -grecord-gcc-switches -o src/curlfunction.cc.o -c src/curlfunction.cc
```

and my link:

```
mpiicpc -qopenmp -shared-intel -rdynamic -qopenmp  <objs>  -o sphere_benchmark -rdynamic <libs> -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_sequential -lmpifort -lmpi -Wl,-Bstatic -lmpigi -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -lrt -lpthread <libs> -Wl,-<libs>
```

I've tried to trim these down to make them vaugley readable whilst still including everything.

Does anyone with experience of Intel XE have any suggestions? I've changed my depreacted `-openmp` flag to `-qopenmp` and according to the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/11/c1/profiling-openmp-applications-with-intel-vtune-amplifier-xe.pdf) it really shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: I only have minor experience with concurrency mode (usually using advanced-hotspots or general-exploration myself), but the following works for me after compiling my program with `-g`: `amplxe-cl -collect concurrency -knob enable-user-sync=true -r ${result_abs_path} -- myProgram nproc=${threads} ${myParameters}`

Comment: I believe also that to run anything more than basic-hotspots, you need to have access to some administrator level files on your computing machine. This was all handled by my systems administrator, so I don't know the details, but it was important to set up on each machine I was planning to profile on in order to take advantage of the sub-clock speed profiling.

Comment: I tired adding nproc similar to you to see if it helped, which it didn't, and the cluster administrator is my flatmate who ran it as root, and still no luck. Thanks though!

Comment: Sorry I should clarify: the `nproc=` option is handled internally in my program to set the number of threads. You can accomplish the same thing by setting the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` before running your program (in either concurrency profiling mode through amplxe or in normal production mode). Sorry I haven't been able to be more helpful though.

Comment: Maybe posting OpenMP region source code would help. Overall I would suggest to post this question on Intel forum. I'm sure that someone at forum will additionally ask you to share  error log files and reproducer; posting then on stackoverflow will rarely help, while posting them on forum will normally lead to getting an answer, workaround and/or fix. It shouldn't be about permissions, because this is concurency analysis (key root-required analysis type is advanced hotspots, which already work for you)